# get_results does not show the last record

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a little problem with showing data from the database. Get_results shows all the records from the database except the last one added. I also have functions for pagination and if I delete it, then displays everything correctly.

Code:

```
global $wpdb;
                $per_page = 10;
                $page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
                if ($page > 1) {
                $offset = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
                } else {
                $offset = $page;
                }


                $show_ad=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM advertisement WHERE active=1 ORDER BY data DESC limit $per_page offset $offset");
        $total = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(id) from advertisement WHERE active=1 ORDER BY data DESC");

~~~~~~
<?php
        echo '<div class="pagination">';
                echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => add_query_arg('cpage', '%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($total / $per_page),
    'current' => $page
));
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: May Be Because Of LIMIT & OFFSET, Only Limited Records Showing.

Comment: Give it a try by adding 1 to your offset : `$offset = $page * $per_page - $per_page + 1;` This is more to debug than the best solution

Comment: your default value of `$offset` must be `0`

Comment: @ThomasG still the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't display the last record because the first row starts with index : 0

EI: if your current page is 1 but your offset in this code is 1

```
offset : 1 which mean starts at index 1 and index 0 will not be included

row 1: 0 - not
row 2: 1 - displayed
row 3: 2 - displayed
row 4: 3 - displayed
row 5: 4 - displayed
row 6: 5 - displayed
row 7: 6 - displayed
row 8: 7 - displayed
row 9: 8 - displayed
row 10: 9 - displayed
row 11: 10 - displayed
```

To solve that subtract your offset to 1

```
$per_page = 10;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
if ($page > 1) {
    $offset = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
} else {
    $offset = $page;
}
$offset = $offset - 1;
```

Comment: @ZYWIEC maybe it's just you dont the the indexes of row(s) that starts with index 0 :)